# wrong image height in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas like this

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

Now I am trying to show image inside the canvas of some 260px width and height. But its showing the image full screened in canvas. What I am doing wrong?

```
img.onload = function(){
                var im = this;
                var imgWidth = im.width;
                var imgHeight = im.height;

                var imgScaledWidth = 0;
                var imgScaledHeight = 0;

                imgScaledHeight = self.conHeight - 40;
                imgScaledWidth = imgScaledHeight * (imgWidth/imgHeight);

                self.context.drawImage(this, 0,0,imgScaledWidth,imgScaledHeight);
            }
```

Its showing like this
[image]

Comment: How big is the image exactly?

Comment: When you do `self.conHeight - 40` what value do you get?  If you just hardcode it to `300` does the image draw correctly?

Comment: self.conHeight is equat to 300 and  subtracting 40 makes it 260

Comment: Sorry it's not clear to me: have you verified that in a debugger or are you saying that's what it *should* be?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why your code shouldn't be working based on what you've shown in the question.  [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/zvATq/2/) based on the code you've given with some minor changes to account for not having a `self` variable.

```
<script>
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var con = c.getContext("2d");

    img.onload = function(){
        var im = this;
        var imgWidth = im.width;
        var imgHeight = im.height;

        var imgScaledWidth = 0;
        var imgScaledHeight = 0;
        var off=20;            

        imgScaledHeight = c.height - off;
        imgScaledWidth = imgScaledHeight * (imgWidth/imgHeight);

    con.drawImage(this, 0,0+(off/2),imgScaledWidth,imgScaledHeight);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: No thats not the required thing. There shld be gap on top and bottom of image inside canvas.

Answer (score 0):

*You are* stretching it. If you don't want to show the image stretched, just don't pass any size to `drawImage`:

```
self.context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
```

Comment: image size is larger than canvas

Comment: @coure2011 what do you want to do then?

Comment: I just want whatever size of canvas is the image shld fit vertically into the container